# structure of cout buffer and endl in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to `C++` learning from `C++ Primer` book. In the first chapter, writer talks about the buffer of the `iostream`, `cout`, and `endl`. I could not understand well. I have two example codes here.

```
#include<iostream>
int v1;
int main()
{

    std::cout<<"First Cout!";
    std::cin>>v1;
    std::cout<<"Second Cout!"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Third Cout!\n";

    return 0;
}
```

I want to know the state of the `cout` buffer after execution of each line.

Comment: Have you ran this code?

Comment: yes code works prefectly

Comment: No, I meant that in the sense that "Have you looked at what it does? Did you try to understand?"

Comment: Yes I know its output even looking it. I have just started to learn what is happening behind the code, what is memory structure, how to optimize the code. you can say a bit advance c++.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The stream contains an in-memory buffer where data is written before being flushed to the final destination (in this case, the output console), since flushing can be an expensive operation.

The buffer might be flushed automatically in some circumstances: when the stream is closed, or if there's a lot of buffered data, or if the stream is configured to flush after each line, as `std::cerr` is.

Sometimes you need to flush manually, for example to make sure the user sees something you've written to `std::cout`. That can be done in two ways:

- calling the `flush()` member function on the stream;
- streaming the `std::flush` manipulator into the stream.

The `std::endl` manipulator does two things:

- inserts a new-line character (or character sequence), equivalent to `<< '\n'`; then
- flushes the stream, equivalent to `<< std::flush`, (which is in turn calls the stream's `flush()` member function).

This is useful for writing short messages to the console; but should be used carefully, as it can have a considerable performance impact when producing large amounts of output.

A further complication is that one stream can be *tied* to another, so that one is flushed before another is accessed. In this case, `cout` is tied to `cin`, which is why you see the first output before reading from `cin` even though there is no explicit flush.

Finally, all the standard streams, including `cout`, are flushed automatically when the program ends (specifically, when the global instance of `std::ios_base::Init` is destroyed; but that's a detail you shouldn't need to know about.)

Comment: almost good and clear answer. Could you please elaborate a little bit more. Why it prints after first line end as there is no endl, flush or \n is called? is this due to the fact that cout is terminated/closed? is steam automatically closed when program is terminated?

Answer (score 1):

After first line, the output is in the buffer, so you will not see it in the terminal.

After the second line, the `endl` causes the buffer to be flushed so you will now see line 1 and 2 in the terminal output.

After the third line, output is in the buffer and you will not see it in the terminal until the program exits.

**Edit:**

When you place a cin between line 1 and 2, it causes cout to be flushed. See: [std::cin](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cin/)

> cin is tied to the standard output stream cout (see ios::tie), which indicates that cout's buffer is flushed (see ostream::flush) before each i/o operation performed on cin.

Comment: what about now? why do I get output of first line before the second line. I have updated the questin.

Answer (score 0):

After 1st line, cout contains just the given string with no newline char.
After 2nd line, cout additionally contains a line ending and the text appears at the console window.
After 3rd line, cout contains another string including line ending which not necessarily appears at the console window.
After exiting main, the text of the 3rd line is appears.

Comment: I have updated the code. after first line executes, cout has string only. According to definition it should not flush out data to the terminal as there is no endl or \n. but at second line it waits for user and it print the first line why so?

Answer (score -3):

std::endl just adds EOL (end of line) symbol to output. Usually its \n, but it can vary from one OS to another.

Comment: It also flushes the buffer afterwards.

Comment: what difference between `std::endl` and `\n` ? I guess there is a great difference in term of the buffer manipulation.

Comment: @MikeSeymour both will flush the buffer?

Comment: printing `'\n'` will not flush the buffer

Comment: @wafeeq at first, "\n" it wont flush output, and at second - end is crossplatform

Comment: Note that *not* flushing is probably what you want most of the time, and `std::endl` is exactly as cross-platform as `'\n'`.